# Unable to get cron to run on AWS Linux AMI

Tags: mysql, cron, amazon-ec2

I am unable to get the cron to run

When I run this:

```
*/1 * * * * root mysqldump -u root  database-name > /var/www/db/database-name.sql
```

I get a 0 size file. But the same command generates a db file from the prompt

Also, this does not do anything, but works fine on prompt

```
*/1 * * * * root mysqldump -u root  database-name > /var/www/db/database-name.sql && aws s3 cp /var/www/db/database-name.sql s3://project-database/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help Steve.

Turns out there was a permission issue for root user. I had the username and password stored in ~/.my.cnf file as

```
[mysqldump]
user = root
password = "password"
```

But I had not called in in the cron statement. Did it this way

```
*/1 * * * * root mysqldump --defaults-extra-file="/root/.my.cnf" -u root   dbname > /var/www/db/dbname.sql && aws s3 cp /var/bd-backups/dbname.sql s3://bucketname/
```

Hope this saves someones time :)